# CSS: How do remove white space caused by letter spacing

Tags: html, css, whitespace, letter-spacing

I'm using letter-spacing in css but it's causing unwanted white-space at the end of my words. How can I remove this?

For instance, doing this:

```
a {
    letter-spacing:2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
```

creates the unwanted space at the end.

I created a fiddle so you can see what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/nhaex8mu/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<span style="letter-spacing:0px;">s</span>
```

for the last letter of the word.

It's not very beautiful code, but it works fine.

Comment: Works indeed. I still think the 'possible duplicate' answer with the :after solution is prettier and more useful if you have a lot of elements. using <span>'s is a lot of work if you have, let's say, 100 elements.